# handling possible simultaneous errors in Python

Tags: python, exception

I just started studying python and I want to know if my approach is the best on handling possible simultaneous errors.

```
Input object is: actor = {"name": "John Cleese", "rank": "awesome"}
```

I defined a function that should return the `"X"` word from the value of `"Y"` property:

```
def get_property(prop, poz):
    ln = actor[prop].split()[poz]
   return ln


#this is how I call my function
_prop = "fname"
_poz = 12

print("The actor's %s is %s" % (_prop, get_property(_prop, _poz)))
```

My goal is that if the property does not exist then use the "name" and/or if the value cannot be split in as many words as the value of "_poz + 1" then pick the first word of the value of that property.

My solution is below so please let me know if there is a better way. Thank you in advance!

```
# Handle all the exceptions!
#Setup
actor = {"name": "John Cleese", "rank": "awesome"}

#This function should return the "poz"th word of property "prop". If an  invalid property is passed then use "name". If an invalid index of the word in the value is passed then use return the first word. 

def get_property(prop, poz):
    ln = ""
    noerr = 0
    while noerr == 0:
        try:
            ln = actor[prop].split()[poz]
        except IndexError:
            poz = 0
        except KeyError:
            prop = "name"    
        else:
            noerr = 1
    return ln

#Test code
_prop = "fname"
_poz = 12

print("The actor's %s is %s" % (_prop, get_property(_prop, _poz)))
```

These are the expected cases and their output:

**Case 1:** valid property and valid word's index

```
_prop = "name"
_poz = 1
get_property(_prop, _poz) = Cleese
```

**Case 2:** valid property and invalid word's index

```
_prop = "name"
_poz = 12
get_property(_prop, _poz) = John
```

**Case 3:** Invalid property and valid word's index

```
_prop = "MIDDLEname"
_poz = 1
get_property(_prop, _poz) = Cleese
```

**Case 4:** Invalid property and invalid word's index

```
_prop = "b-rank"
_poz = 12
get_property(_prop, _poz) = John
```

Answer (score 1):

## What you are doing

#### "Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3.7/glossary.html#term-eafp)

In your code you just use the parameters you got and hope that everything works fine (`try`). If that's not the case (`except`), you change the parameter accordingly and try it again (`while`) until it works (`else`).

So basically what you are doing is validating your input **afterwards**.
This comes with a lot of extra code (`try`, `except`, etc.).
But actually, that's the preferred coding style according of Python

But in your case, especially as beginner, your approach has the following **disadvantages**:

- Your code becomes **more complex** and **harder to read** because you use many different techniques in one function (`try` with multiple `except` in a `while` loop)

  - You can't spot easily if you maybe forgot a case!
- Your code becomes **slower** to execute (you won't feel the difference in this case but it's good to know), for example:

  - In the worst case (`IndexError` + `KeyError`) you have to go through your `while` loop 3 times
- Your code becomes **"unsafer"**, for example:

  - What would happen if the `actor` dictionary is changed and the `name` key gets removed? Your code would stuck in an endless loop, because the `try-except` construct would catch the exception every time, not executing the `else` case.

## What you should do

#### "Look before you leap" [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/3.7/glossary.html#term-lbyl)

So a better solution in your case would be to validate your input **before** you try to work with it.

In your case you are working with two different [data structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) ([`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) and [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list)):

- For your dictionary you can use the `get(key, default)` method to safely get the value you want from the dictionary
- For your list of splitted words you can check if there are enough words with the `len(list)` method

These methods will help you to avoid the exceptions at all.
Just add the logic to your `get_property` function to make sure every error case is handled properly:

```
actor = {"name": "John Cleese", "rank": "awesome"}

def get_property(prob, pos, default="name"):
    values = actor.get(prob, actor[default]).split()
    return values[pos] if pos < len(values) else values[0]

test_values = [("name", 1), ("name", 12), ("MIDDLEname", 1), ("b-rank", 12)]
for prob, pos in test_values:
    print(f"{prob}, {pos} => {get_property(prob, pos)}")
```

This produces the output:

```
name, 1 => Cleese
name, 12 => John
MIDDLEname, 1 => Cleese
b-rank, 12 => John
```

Comment: That's a correct answer, but probably over the head of the OP if they just started studying Python. They likely do not know the `.get()` method of dicts, or the string interpolation tricks. Maybe you could add a bit more details of what does what?

Comment: @Leporello I hope my changes cover that now

Comment: Excellent. I would just have added links to [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl) vs [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) (Python has an EAFP-oriented philosophy, but LBYL is certainly better for that use case).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The solution is elegant and I highly appreciate it (I learned something not shown in the tutorial ;)). I was learning about exceptions and that's how I came up with the question: How can I catch and handle two or more exceptions at the same time?

Comment: @Leporello thanks for the links! I updated my answer one more time. Sadly not many people will see it. Even I learned something new, thanks!

Comment: @Idoneus I slightly updated my code and my answer (I added a `default` parameter)